# Summary pop up of the questions(when holding mouse on it) appears only in the main page

Tags: feature-request, design

Recently I've noticed that the summary pop up of the question (when I hold the mouse on it) works only in the main page of SO. In other parts of the site like:

- [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)
- [Questions/newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest)
- [Questions/featured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured)
- [Questions/frequent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=frequent)
- [Questions/votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes)
- [Questions/active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active)
- [Questions/unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered)

or in *custom tags* (like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and so on) *the little pop up doesn't appear*. The same situation is for *Unanswered* button (with its related tags).

It works perfectly fine in main page with its related tags *interesting*, *featured*, *hot*, *week*, *month* but not in the above links.

For me it is very helpful this little trick because when *I hold the mouse on a question* I can figure out if I'm interested in that question (or I just cannot help the person who asked that question because I don't know the answer ...and so on). Of course I usually go to that link with the question I'm interested in (or just to read the answers for improving my programming skills) but the little summary is quite helpful in many cases.

**Is this a some bug or just the summary pop ups was made only for the main page (maybe for the performance it wasn't included this feature)?**

Usually I (and I think most users) am going to specific tags (like [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net) and so on...) where this summary pop up doesn't appear when I'm holding the mouse on a question. It'll be very nice if this feature will work everywhere not only in the main page.

I'm using IE 10 and Google Chrome 34.0

Comment: Perhaps because the homepage is the *only place* that shows only the question title? The rest has a summary directly in the page and doesn't need the title.

Comment: It would be nice to include this feature in at least first three tags with the most followers on stackoverflow :)

Comment: The information is not expensive to produce; it's a question about how much you fit in the page. The same info is *there*, but displayed below the question title. The homepage *doesn't have more info*.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't noticed that. Indeed in the home page there are just the questions without the question title (which is displayed as a pop up when the user hold on it) but in the rest of the site the header of the question is displayed bellow (which make no sense to display as a pop up as is already bellow). Thanks for response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The homepage mouseover tooltip *does not contain any more info* than what is displayed on the other pages.

The rest of the site displays the excerpt right below the title instead. Compare the following two screenshots, for example; one is from the *interesting* tab on the homepage, the other from the specific tag page:

[image]

[image]

That's the *exact same excerpt*, only presented differently. A tooltip on that page would be useless because the same info is already there.